# SSRS Position calculate Expression

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to show the Postions of student on the basis of aggregate (aggregate )
[image]

The Aggregate expressions calculating on basis of (FINAL + MOCK + Asst)/3 which m doing on run time expression calculate...

Now i am unable to display the position positions Column highest the aggregate highest positions(1 OR 2 OR 3 ) positions
Is there any expression i can write to  show positions column.
please help me m stuck

Answer (score 0):

There's not a function that you can use - you'd just need to use some IIFs:

```
=IIF(FIELDS!Final.VALUE >= FIELDS!Mock.VALUE AND FIELDS!Final.VALUE >= FIELDS!Asst.VALUE, 1, 
 IIF(FIELDS!Mock.VALUE  >= FIELDS!Final.VALUE AND FIELDS!Mock.VALUE >= FIELDS!Asst.VALUE, 2, 3))
```